# How to connect Google adwords with Python

Tags: python, api, google-ads-api

Hi I am looking for a simple solution to connect Google Adwords with Python in jupyter notebook, went through google on some blogs and websites but did not get a proper solution.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The API quickstart is an excellent and easily digestible guide.
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/first-call/overview

There's no reason this cannot be done in a Juypter notebook. What code are you using that isn't working?